# Can I extend an API controller to hold a variable for my database Context?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have many classes like this one. They all have two things in common. They declare a private variable called Context and they have a method to dipose of that.

Is there a way I can create an intermediate class that I could inherit from that has the code to declare the variable and the dispose method? I assume it's easy to do but I am not sure how to declare the variables and the method. Should they be private?

```
public class TypeController : ApiController
{
    private Context db = new Context();

    [Route("GetMapData")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetMapData()
    {
        var result = await db.Types
                             .Select(e => new
                             {
                                 Id = e.TypeId,
                                 Name = e.Name
                             })
                             .ToListAsync();
        return Ok(result);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a base class that does that, and you'd declare the `db` variable as `protected`

```
public class BaseController : ApiController
{
    protected Context db = new Context();

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}

public class TypeController : BaseController
{   
    [Route("GetMapData")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetMapData()
    {
        var result = await db.Types
                             .Select(e => new
                             {
                                 Id = e.TypeId,
                                 Name = e.Name
                             })
                             .ToListAsync();
        return Ok(result);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've better to use dependency injection.

Try some dependency resolver to maintain object life time
You can start from here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver